# Book about a murderer's apprentice in 1800s London, who ends up time traveling

Tags: story-identification, books

In this book, there is a boy who is an apprentice under a murderer in I believe the 1800s.
The boy ends up killing a guy and then I forget how, but time travels to the future.

He ends up in a place that I forget, but the man he murdered was the owner's father, and he was in the time travel pod with him.

Later in the book you find out that the murderer who is training the boy was a magician, who had once done the [box cutting with a saw trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawing_a_woman_in_half) on the woman he loved. The trick went wrong and one of his gloves was stained red with blood.

I believe the title had WIP or something in it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Was this book a draft when you read it? WIP often stands for "work in progress"

Comment: I believe that I read it in 2016 - 2017, I don't think it was a work in progress. It may have been WPP because I do believe the boy was put into witness protection program.

Answer (score 4):

*The Reluctant Assassin* (2013) by Eoin Colfer, first book of the "W.A.R.P." series.

From [the author's website](https://www.eoincolfer.com/works/warp-book-1):

> **Riley, a teen orphan boy living in Victorian London, has had the misfortune of being apprenticed to Albert Garrick, an illusionist** who has fallen on difficult times and now uses his unique conjuring skills to gain access to victims’ dwellings. On one such escapade, **Garrick brings his reluctant apprentice along and urges him to commit his first killing.  Riley is saved from having to commit the grisly act when the intended victim turns out to be a scientist from the future**, part of the FBI’s **Witness Anonymous Relocation Program (WARP) Riley is unwittingly transported via wormhole to modern day London**, followed closely by Garrick.
>
> In modern London, Riley is helped by Chevron Savano, a nineteen-year-old FBI agent sent to London as punishment after a disastrous undercover, anti-terrorist operation in Los Angeles. Together Riley and Chevie must evade Garrick, who has been fundamentally altered by his trip through the wormhole. Garrick is now not only evil, but he also possesses all of the scientist’s knowledge. **He is determined to track Riley down and use the timekey in Chevie’s possession** to make his way back to Victorian London where he can literally change the world.

---

Found with the Google query `scifi book london assassin apprentice time travel -hobb`, which brought up an Amazon link. The `-hobb` part of the query aims to filter out everything pertaining to Robin Hobb's [*Assassin's Apprentice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin%27s_Apprentice), which is completely unrelated, but matches enough keywords to clutter the results with false positives.